# Mysql Search String issue in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i want to search my mysql with following code, but its some sort of problem with string search variable. if i can change $Title variable with simple test string, like 'hello world' its searched by query but, in following case, this query return 'boolean false'

```
foreach ($catgories as $Title => $Url) {

$Title = str_replace(array('-','_'), '', $Title);
$Title = strtolower($Title);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id FROM ci_contents WHERE cat_title LIKE '%{$Title}%'") OR die(mysql_error());
$query= mysql_fetch_array($query);

var_dump($query);
exit;
}
```

Comment: check `$Title` value in the loop by echoing it

Comment: if i echo $Title, it return right value, but this value not proceed through MYSQL LIKE query

Comment: Any chance of white spaces in `$Title`? Try `$Title = trim(strtolower($Title));`

Comment: are mysql error??`while(mysql_fetch_array($query) as $rec)echo $rec;` Try it.

Comment: Poldas, you are right, it's all because of some white space in string,  thanks